# Select Columns from 2 Tables with Subquery where Record Exists in Both Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a collection table. It's sort of the mother table (let's call it R which maps out to 3 other tables. I'm interested in one of those 3 (let's call it C)

Unfortunately I don't know the insert logic for those tables, but I want to select columns from R and C where C.Hash exists in R.Hash

So far I'm at:

```
select 
    r.column1, r.column2, c.column3, c.column4 
from 
    r 
where 
    exists (select 1 from c
            where c.hash = r.hash)
```

How do I bind the c columns? Or is this syntax completely off?

If anyone could complete the query that'd be great, or at least let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a join:

```
SELECT r.column1, r.column2, c.column3, c.column4 
FROM r
INNER JOIN c
    ON c.hash = r.hash;
```

Your `EXISTS` logic is correct, but the way you have written the query only allows you to select from the `r` table.  A join exposes the columns of both tables.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that helps, but I kind of wanted to learn the syntax, because I am also interested incorporating another one of those 3 tables (call it M). Lets say I wanted to select R.column1, C.Column2, M.Column3, and if it wasn't in C on a join, it'd then try to find a record from M. (lets imagine there's only 2 of the 3 tables I mentioned)

Comment: Please don't change your question once people have answered it.